# <Text> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

Seems like I may have configured something incorrectly here where react-native components are getting labeled as non-native components because of casing, but it's clear that the components have uppercase letter already. What's going on here?

```
  console.error
    Warning: The tag <Text> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
        at Text
        at Component (/Project/node_modules/react-native/jest/mockComponent.js:28:18)
        at View
        at Component (/Project/node_modules/react-native/jest/mockComponent.js:28:18)
        at Index (/Project/pages/index.tsx:17:18)

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:67:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:43:5)
      at createElement (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9027:9)
      at createInstance (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10192:20)
      at completeWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19464:28)
      at completeUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22812:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22787:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-dom+17.0.1.patch

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js b/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js
index d51615a..42b7495 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js
+++ b/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js
@@ -2722,9 +2722,11 @@ function assertValidProps(tag, props) {
 }
 
 function isCustomComponent(tagName, props) {
-  if (tagName.indexOf('-') === -1) {
-    return typeof props.is === 'string';
-  }
+  // Added to suppress this warning here
+  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194105/text-is-unrecognized-in-this-browser-if-you-meant-to-render-a-react-component
+  // Is seemed to be here because it's how web-component inherit, but it's not necessary
+  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-is
+  // Accounts for custom components all having dashes
+  // https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/webcomponents-design-guidelines/#other-considerations
+  if (tagName.indexOf('-') !== -1) return true;
+  // accounts for components having upper case letters
+  if (tagName == tagName.toLowerCase()) return false;
 
   switch (tagName) {
     // These are reserved SVG and MathML elements.
```

Comment: i have the same problem, but i dont have `react-dom`, as my app is intended for mobile only. do I NEED react-dom to run tests successfully?

Comment: @benwl I'm not sure, sorry I can't be of more help